# How to style a custom control Mouse Over - Hover - MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm using this [toolkit](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid) for WinRT and developing a Windows 8.1 business app which has a datagrid to show app's parameters.

My app has a Black background and when I hover the mouse over the items of the grid (on pc, not on tablet) the text changes to black. This way the user is unable to read the content of under hover.

I was able to change the grid background trying to find the Hover property anywhere, without success. 
Here is how I'm changing the background:

```
<controls:DataGrid Height="Auto"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Params, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       x:Name="gridParams"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       View:EventHandlers.Attach="SelectionChanged => SelectionChangedHandler($sender)"

                       DefaultOrderIndex="0">
        <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="controls:DataGrid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>


        </controls:DataGrid.Resources>....
```

Has anybody been using this toolkit?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the VisualStates. There is generally one for "PointerOver", which can use to change the style of your control.

Comment: @NateDiamond Thanks for your comment but there is not a PointOver on this Object.

Comment: There is, it's just stored deep in the XAML for the object. I'll add an answer, as the explanation for this is a bit detailed.

Comment: My Bad Nate! I'm sorry I could not find before. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries! It was deep in the source and not readily accessible (I couldn't find the source on CodePlex, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [DataGrid Style](https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/MyToolkit.Extended.WinRT/Themes/generic.xaml), one thing you will notice is that the main template for the DataGrid simply contains a `NavigationList` (one of the toolkits own controls), with a custom `Style`, `TransparentListBox`, which is `BasedOn` the `ListBox` style.

The `NavigationList` is actually an `ExtendedListBox`, another one of the custom controls.

Both of these inherit their `ItemContainerStyle`s from that of the `ListBox`, as they do not override it.

This means that each item is actually inheriting the default [`ListBoxItem Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709919.aspx).

One thing you'll note from this `Style` is that it has a bunch of defined `VisualStates`, including:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Now, there are a couple of ways of fixing this problem. The simplest (but most invasive) way is to override the values in your `App.Xaml`, like so.

```
<Application
    ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#21000000" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Green" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This will change the brushes for *all* `ListBox`es though, so it may be less than idea.

The next solution is to override just the ListBoxItem template for your current control. This is slightly more difficult and requires a lot more code, but it would go something like this:

```
<controls:DataGrid
    ...>
    <controls:DataGrid.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:DataGrid">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" x:Name="titles" />
                <controls:NavigationList BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             Style="{StaticResource TransparentListBox}" Margin="0" x:Name="list" >
                    <controls:NavigationList.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,10" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             To="1"
                                                                             Duration="0" />
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             To="1"
                                                                             Duration="0" />
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             To="1"
                                                                             Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid"
                                                  Background="Transparent">
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground"
                                                           Fill="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                           Opacity="0" />
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                           Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                                           StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                                           StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                                           Opacity="0"
                                                           StrokeDashOffset=".5" />
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                           Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                                           StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                                           StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                                           Opacity="0"
                                                           StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </controls:NavigationList.ItemContainerStyle>
                </controls:NavigationList>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </controls:DataGrid.Template>
</controls:DataGrid>


    </controls:DataGrid.Template>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Just replace the two references to `ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush` and `ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush` to whatever new values you'd like.

While this may seem like a bunch of hassle, you can now change the colors of each item to be anything you want to be while hovering. If you have a bunch of these, you can also store off the custom `DataGrid Style` and reuse it.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Did you find an error in the datagrid i should change directly in its code/style?

Comment: Not necessarily an error, but possibly adding an overridable ItemStyle property would make it a lot simpler. OP could have done it himself, but I figured it'd be easier to just give him a pure XAML answer that he could use once and forget.